# as400 connection via vba excel macro | provider can't be found

Tags: excel, vba, database, connection-string, ibm-midrange

I need to connect to As400 via vba excel macro. I am using the following connection string:

```
strCon = "PROVIDER=IBMDA400;DATA SOURCE= xxxxx" & "; USER ID=" & UserId & "; PASSWORD=" & pwd
con.Open strCon
```

But i am getting following error. Can someone help me in figuring out if i need to make any additional settings to y macro or if my connection string itself is incorrect.

[image]

Comment: do you have the IBM ODBC driver?  On a windows PC, start menu, then ODBC data sources.  Look in the system DSN and then user DSN tabs. If the drive is installed, you see it listed there. If not there, download "IBM access client solutions" from IBM. I think you need the application package to make sure the ODBC drivers are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did RockBoro sugestion help you fix your problem?  If not you may want to try another avenue to test the signon process use this string I have tested successfully (which my ip of course).
Con.Open "provider=IBMDA400;data source=89.31.143.1"

if a manual sign on screen opens you know there is a problem with the signon to your system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).